# Null pointer exception while consuming streams

Tags: java-8, stream, flatmap

```
{
   "rules": [
      {
         "rank": 1,
         "grades": [
            {
               "id": 100,
               "hierarchyCode": 32
            },
            {
               "id": 200,
               "hierarchyCode": 33
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "rank": 2,
         "grades": []
      }
   ]
}
```

I've a json like above and I'm using streams to return "hierarchyCode" based on some condition. For example if I pass "200" my result should print 33. So far I did something like this:

```
request.getRules().stream()
        .flatMap(ruleDTO -> ruleDTO.getGrades().stream())
        .map(gradeDTO -> gradeDTO.getHierarchyCode())
        .forEach(hierarchyCode -> {
           //I'm doing some business logic here
           Optional<SomePojo> dsf = someList.stream()
              .filter(pojo -> hierarchyCode.equals(pojo.getId())) // lets say pojo.getId() returns 200
              .findFirst();
           System.out.println(dsf.get().getCode());
        });
```

So in the first iteration for the expected output it returns `33`, but in the second iteration it is failing with Null pointer instead of just skipping the loop since "`grades`" array is empty this time. How do I handle the null pointer exception here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the below code snippet using Java 8:**

```
int result;
int valueToFilter = 200;
List<Grade> gradeList = data.getRules().stream().map(Rule::getGrades).filter(x-> x!=null && !x.isEmpty()).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
Optional<Grade> optional = gradeList.stream().filter(x -> x.getId() == valueToFilter).findFirst();
if(optional.isPresent()){
result = optional.get().getHierarchyCode();
System.out.println(result);
```

}

I have created POJO's according to my code, you can try this approach with your code structure.

In case you need POJO's as per this code, i will share the same as well.

*Thanks,*
**Girdhar**